# Camera not tracking empty

Tags: animation, camera, bezier-curves, constraints, parent

I want my camera to track the pillows on top of the bed so I added an empty and added a constraint to the camera.
[image]

these are my settings for the constraint so that the camera points to the empty
[image]

Then i have a curve path for the camera to follow. I added another empty so that could be the parent of the camera
[image]

I don't understand my camera won't track the target.
[image]

Even grabing the camera to see if the camera tracks doesn't work as well. Did I do something wrong?

Here's the blend file
[image]

Comment: hello, is it possible to share your file? I think there is some problem sith rotation, origin points or things like this. If your modifier is red it means that it does nothing... did you try to change setting in your modifiers or order of the modifiers?

Comment: @MikoCG it's taking time to upload please wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I guessed, the wrong order of the modifiers and settings was the cause:
[image]

Just take **track to** modifier and pull it under the **child of** modifier and then click on **Z** and **Y** again (to reset it or something) and it works, btw it is a really nice concept.

For that rotation of the camera, this is yours:
[image]

Your curve cannot pass through that green line, that causes that rotation you see... you need to adjust it a little if you don't want to change the whole camera setting a little bit like this:

[image]

In this case it works right

Comment: It works now but there's this weird camera rotation. I think its automatically adjusting its tracking. Is there a way to fix this or do I have to just keyframe this manually instead of adding a constraint?

Comment: you mean the thing at the beggining? That happens because camera always tries to face upwards in this settings. At the beginning of the motion your curve takes camera in a bit wrong direction and camera will change it's Z rotation because you just flipped it upside down. I am not sure if you understand but you should adjust curve by a little

Comment: I edited my answer for this rotation

Comment: thank you again :>>>>